# Get Field Value For Linq Query - SharePoint

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint, csom

I'm stuck trying to limit my results between a date range. I'm connecting to SharePoint using the CSOM. The SharePoint version I think is SharePoint Online (we have office 365 at work).

Basically, I want to limit the dates returned on the query below. I want the **Start_Date <= Today** and the **End_Date >= Today**. More than that I'm not quite understanding how to return a field's value using linq.

I added this:

`.Where(x => x.Id <= 50)`

which is working correctly. This was easy as I could find the `Id` property with Intellisense, but I can't find how to pull out the fields I'm interested in, and, how to use linq to limit my results with an additional Where.

Right now I get the following error trying to run my code as is:

`The 'ToDateTime' member cannot be used in the expression.`

**Relevant Code:**

```
    private ListItemCollection GetSharePointList(string XML, string tableName, ClientContext context, byte limit = 50)
    {
        List testTable = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(tableName);

        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery
        {
            ViewXml = XML //The Passed in XML is: "<view></view>"
        };

        ListItemCollection GetSharePointList = testTable.GetItems(camlQuery);
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

        context.Load(GetSharePointList,
        items => items.Take(limit).Include(
                 item => item.Id,
                 item => item["DayOfMonth"],
                 item => item["Start_Date"],
                 item => item["End_Date"],
                 item => item["Task_FrequencyID_x003a_Frequency"],
                 item => item["TaskID_x003a_TaskName"],
                 item => item["TaskID_x003a_TaskAlias"],
                 item => item["TaskID_x003a_TaskDueTime"],
                 item => item["Daily_Frequency_x003a_DayofWeek"],
                 item => item["Weekly_Frequency_x003a_Week"],
                 item => item["End_Date"],
                 item => item["Monthly_Frequency"])
                        .Where(x => x.Id <= 50)
                        .Where(y => Convert.ToDateTime(y.FieldValues["Start_Date"]) <= today));

        context.ExecuteQuery();
        return GetSharePointList;
    }
```

Comment: Should be something like .Select(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Start_Date"))

Comment: @jdweng Thanks. I'm getting "ListItem does not contain a definition for 'Field' ..." any ideas?

Comment: The field is an object that can be any typo.  So without knowing the type I can't give an answer.  The item may already be a DateTime so there is no need to convert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restrict the results between Start_Date <= Today and the End_Date >= Today, you need to use CAML query. That is how it works in SharePoint.

So, you need to modify your code as below:

```
List testTable = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(tableName);

var viewQuery = string.Format(@"<View>
    <Query>
      <Where>
        <And>        
         <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name='Start_Date' />
            <Value Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value>
         </Leq>
         <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name='End_Date' />
            <Value Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value>
         </Geq>
      </And>
     </Where>
    </Query>
</View>");

CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery
{
    ViewXml = viewQuery;
};

ListItemCollection GetSharePointList = testTable.GetItems(camlQuery);

context.Load(GetSharePointList,
    items => items.Include(
    item => item.Id,
    item => item["DayOfMonth"],
    item => item["Start_Date"],
    item => item["End_Date"],
    item => item["Task_FrequencyID_x003a_Frequency"],
    item => item["TaskID_x003a_TaskName"],
    item => item["TaskID_x003a_TaskAlias"],
    item => item["TaskID_x003a_TaskDueTime"],
    item => item["Daily_Frequency_x003a_DayofWeek"],
    item => item["Weekly_Frequency_x003a_Week"],
    item => item["End_Date"],
    item => item["Monthly_Frequency"]));
context.ExecuteQuery();

foreach(ListItem spListItem in GetSharePointList){
    //do something with the data
}
```

Reference - [Retrieve list items using CSOM C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee534956(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Gautam. My preference would be to restrict the list by using Linq if possible. Are you saying this can only be achieved with a CAML query?

Comment: Yes, to restrict results you need to use CAML query only.

Comment: Why did `.Where(x => x.Id <= 50)` work to restrict those records if you can only restrict with CAML?

Comment: Apologies, but i think it could do with some limited functions then since you mentioned that it was available via intellisense. Have never really used LINQ extensively in SharePoint. But in our daily use, we use CAML queries only to restrict data.

Comment: When you use LINQ to create queries against the client object model, you are using LINQ to Objects, not the LINQ to SharePoint provider, which can only be used when you write code against the server object model. 
In another words when you use LINQ with CSOM you pull all items from server and do filtering locally with LINQ.